# File Handler method in selenium doesn't throw any IO Exception even if the file is not present

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

```
import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        FileHandler.copy(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Abc"), new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Abc2"));
    }

}
```

The above code works correctly when the path is valid but when the path is invalid or the file is not present it doesnt throw any IO exception.

I ran the above code in intellij and eclipse but couldnt see any error when i did the same thing with java.io it throws error.

Comment: Well, the method isn't even documented. According to its source code (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/02a0df9d72273415c02bc8da6f517585e7fb8123/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/io/FileHandler.java#L110), that seems like the desired behavior. But I wouldn't use an undocumented API, especially when the standard and documented Java API allows doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an expected behavior, as the API says below -

```
  public static void copy(File from, File to) throws IOException {
    if (!from.exists()) {
      return;
    }

    if (from.isDirectory()) {
      copyDir(from, to);
    } else {
      copyFile(from, to);
    }
  }
```

So if the file is not present it just returns.

```
if (!from.exists()) {
      return;
    }
```

Comment: If so when does it throw IOException !

Comment: Please try making a fake "to" file path.

Comment: FYI ,please refer my question, i mentioned i have tried with invalid path and it doesn't throw any IO Exception

Comment: Try to give a drive letter like K which is not present in your file system.

It will throw error. Like this

FileHandler.copy(new File("C:\Users\Desktop\Abc"), new File("K:\Users\Desktop\Abc2"));

Hillol